# How to with enabling horizontal scrolling on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

index.html

```
<div name="MainContent" id="MainContent" class="MainContent">

</div>
```

index.sass

```
body, html
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0 0 0 0

    #MainContent
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        margin: -250px 0 0 100px;
        float: left;
        width: 2000px;
        min-width: 2000px;
        max-width: 2000px;
        height: 500px;
        min-height: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
        top: 50%;
```

Horizontal scrolling is working, however, only by using the bar at the bottom of the page. If i attempt to use the scroll wheel the page will not scroll. Any ideas as to why that is and how to make that work?

Comment: By setting your `#MainContent` fit or smaller than your screen and add `overflow-x: true` to enable scrolling if content is overflow.

Comment: So would i add `overflow-x: true` in the `html` selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove your body scroll property, add `overflow:hidden` to your html or body styles.

```
body,html {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

To make your div scrollable, set its width to 100%, and enable horizontal scrolling by adding `overflow-x:auto`. Now the width of the div will be 100% to the body , and if the content inside the div has higher width, then the scroll will get enabled.

```
#MainContent {
   width:100%; /* you can even set a static width here, which could be less than the body width*/
   overflow-x:auto;
}
```

NB: Please REMOVE the `min-width:2000px` and `max-width:2000px` from the `#MainContent` style